# Redirect to Different Page While Using the Same HTML Template/File?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, csv, url

I have a list of players, I'll show an example to give a basic idea:

```
<div>
  <ul id="playerNames">
      <li><b>Harden</b></li>
      <li><b>Giannis</b></li>
      <li><b>Lebron</b></li>
      <li><b>Booker</b></li>
      <li><b>Lavine</b></li>
      <li><b>Westbrook</b></li>
      <li><b>Jokic</b></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is create a different URL for each player, so that when clicked on, the user will be redirected to a new page where I will display information such as the player's stats, shot charts, bio, etc. Is there a way for me to have a single HTML file/template to handle all of these (~500) players? Each page will be essentially the same in structure, all that will change are the actual numbers and images displayed, which I have stored in csvs and other locations that I would like to load in.

Example line of a csv (column names not shown here) This is only here if anyone is for whatever reason unfamiliar with what a csv is:

```
203932,Aaron Gordon,1610612753,ORL,24.0,58,28,30,0.483,1913.7333333333333,314,726,0.433,68,226,0.301,137,203,0.675,103,338,441,215,94,50,36,41,116,188,833,-96,1848.7,19,1,117,140,392,242,41,77,64,273,141,108,320,75,58,352,41,28,26,62,85,106,77,448,372,52,83,420,52,28,16,5,"203932,1610612753"
```

I was looking into query strings and was thinking they may be the best way to do this, but I have never used them before so this may not be true.

Anyways, it boils down to me trying to avoid creating 500+ html files that are all going to look almost identical. If anybody has a solution for this, I am all ears.

Comment: Link it to the same page but with different URL parameters? Then read ID/name from URL and show data for that specific user.

Comment: I believe that is what I am trying to do. Excuse my ignorance for not knowing exactly what that is. But if a URL parameter is basically just having the same page but with different "settings" based on how I got there, then that sounds like exactly what I am going for.

Comment: This is pretty much an opinion-based question. People could suggest query strings, or js frameworks, any type of db, etc. It's way too broad for SO.

Comment: Deda says for each player create a link as `<a href="?player=203932">Aaron Gordon</a>`, than based on player ID show other data on same page.

Comment: Yes skobaljic, that's exactly what I am looking to do. Thanks Deda for identifying my request. But what code will I need to make the "?player=203932" at the end of the url lead to a functional page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by skobaljic, adding `"?=playerid"` to the url is (in my opinion) the best solution here. Query strings make this a fairly easy task. My solution to this was the following:

In PHP when making the list, add a link containing the player id into the URL using a query string:

```
<a href='nba_player_stats_page.html?player=" . $ids[0] . "'>"
```

Then, in a separate PHP file, grab the page URL, then snap off the ID to match the ID of the player clicked on:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$id = substr($url, strpos($url, "=") + 1);
```

Finally, just use ajax to load in the php file:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'nba_player_stats.php',
  method: 'GET',
  success:function(res){
    $('#playerStats').html(res)
    // $('#playerNames').replaceWith(res);
  }
})
```

This basic structure should help anyone with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all of the player info to be all in one page on a separate .html file, then you can wrap the `<b>PlayerName</b>` tags with a `<a>` tag like so:
`<a href="playerInfo.html"><b>PlayerName</b></a>`
playerInfo.html is the page that all the player info is on. Then, add an id to the HTML element with that player info so the link automatically scrolled the page down to the element with that id:

**index.html:**

`<a href="playerInfo.html#Harden"><b>Harden</b></a>`

**playInfo.html:**

```
<div id="Harden">
 PLAYER INFO HTML
</div>
```